# Using the clipper tool on QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, extract

I am using the clipper tool to cut a raster layer to a shapefile. I have done this successfully to 2 raster layers. Now I am working on a third raster layer from a different source and when I hit okay to clip the layer, it just acts like it is trying to load forever. It never completes the process, and it never throws an error.

Why would this be?

---

For the layer that clipped correctly, the CRS is w6884, and for the one that didn't work, it is nad83

It seems that any operation I try to perform on this raster layer never completes, yet doesn't throw an error. Is there something wrong about the layer I am using?

The file that works was .bil and the one that didn't work is a .adf. I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: what is the difference between the third raster and the others? Extent, projection, ...?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I just looked at the properties and metadata. The layer extents are very different, and the resolution (is that the same as coordinate reference system?) is also different.

Comment: @LHowe reproject shapefile to clip the third raster. To reproject, go to `save as`, select the desire projection and create te new file

Comment: If you turn "on-the-fly-reprojection" **OFF**; do raster and shapefile still overlap?

Comment: Okay, so I just changed the settings to turn that off, and the shapefile just kinda dissapeared?

Comment: Did the shapefile actually disappear, or did it just move? Try "zoom global" and I suspect you will see that the shapefile is now quite far away from the rasters.